# How does Apple's downloadable/executable code restriction tally with using  HTML5 and Javascript in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, app-store

The app store review guidelines states:

"Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejcted"
"Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected".

However HTML and Javascript is code. Therefore how does this restriction tally with the use of UIWebView? 
The use of UIWebView in an app must by definition (excluding loading local content) be downloading and executing code mustn't it? Therefore according to a verbatim strict interpretation of the App Store Review Guidelines, any app which uses UIWebView is in contravention of them.

So can you use UIWebView only with HTML5 for example and no Javascript, but how can this possibly be policed?

Therefore how does Apple review apps using UIWebView? What do they allow and what do they not allow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read your agreement again.

> 3.3.2 An Internal Use Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework.

UIWebView uses the built-in WebKit framework. You are free to download HTML/JS/CSS and render it in  UIWebView.